# Import node.js variable into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

I wrote this code and I am trying to run it in order to update database with a node.js variable. Script works but inputs the string "$var" instead of the actual result. Please help.

Thank you.

```
var TOTP = require('onceler').TOTP;
    setInterval(function() {
    // create a TOTP object with your Secret
    var totp = new TOTP('CODEHERE');
    $var:{totp.now}
    // print out a code that's valid right now
    console.log(totp.now());
    $q="UPDATE auth SET auth =$var where id='1'";
    con.query(
      $q,function(err,rows){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data received');
    console.log(rows);
    })},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$q="UPDATE auth SET auth = '" + $var + "' where id='1'";
```